# In Ubuntu 17.10, how to rearrange icons in dock

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, dock, ubuntu-dock

In Ubuntu 17.10, how do I rearrange the application icons in the dock area?
I have tried many ways but failed, such as:

1. right-click the icons
2. left-click or right-click the empty space in the dock

Answer (score 11):

Drag & drop! See the animated image below.

[image]

---

The solution above may be outdated or non-working. To rearrange the icons of the applications "pinned" (i.e. added to favourites) to the dock in the Terminal way, do this:

First open Terminal and run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

You should get the list of `.desktop` files associated to the applications pinned to the dock in order, something like the following:

```
['appname-1.desktop', 'appname-2.desktop', 'appname-3.desktop', 'appname-4.desktop', 'appname-5.desktop']
```

Suppose you want to move the icon of the application associated to `appname-3.desktop` to the first position. In that case, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps "['appname-3.desktop', 'appname-1.desktop', 'appname-2.desktop', 'appname-4.desktop', 'appname-5.desktop']"
```

and so on.

Comment: Favourite icons can also be edited using the excellent `dconf Editor` at `/org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps`. If not installed, use `apt-get install dconf-editor -y`.

Answer (score 0):

Also for users of Ubuntu 18.04. If you have the `Auto-hide the Dock` (the Dock hides when a window overlaps) option activated you need to turn it off first so you can drag & drop your icons to rearrange them on the Dock (Settings > Dock > Auto-hide the Dock). It looks that this option also locks the Dock icons without mention it in the option hints or other documentation.

Cheers.